# My Javascript code crashes in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

**Hello**,
I am just starting to learn programming with javascript and i made a "game" where the computer generates a random number and you should guess it, however when i press the button to start playing the browser freezes like if there is an infinite loop. I tryed removing the loop "Do" and the game worked fine, however i can't get working the counter that registers the number of attempts made by the user before finding the correct number, because without loop every time i click the button "Go" in order to run the script the variable "counter" gets back to 0.., the text in the game is in Spanish, if you can't understand howthe program works because of it please tell me and i will translate it even further.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Prueba de Juego</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

//Selector de Modo
var modo=0;

function configuracion(){
    var pregunta;
    pregunta=confirm("[Seleccionar Modo] Would you like to use a custom range of values to generate the number?, if not we will proceed using standard mode.");

    if (pregunta==true) {
        modo=1;
        var cambiar=document.getElementById('modo').innerHTML='<span id="modo" style="color: blue;">Modo Personalizado</span>';

    }else{

        modo=2;
        var cambiar2=document.getElementById('modo').innerHTML='<span id="modo" style="color: green;">Modo Estandard</span>';

    }
}

function juego(){
    var contador,numero,ingresar,adivinar,aproximacion,minimo,maximo,mingen,maxgen;
    contador=0;
    numero=0;
    minimo=100;
    maximo=1000;
    mingen=0;
    maxgen=0;

    //Verificar que modo se utiliza
    if(modo=="0"){alert("[Atención] Modo no seleccionado.");return;}

    //Modo Personalizado
    if(modo=="1"){

        mingen=document.getElementById("mingen").value;
        maxgen=document.getElementById("maxgen").value;

        if(mingen=="" || maxgen==""){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: #DBA901;">Please type in the maximum and minimum values..</span>';
            return;
        }

        //Procesar a integer
        mingen=parseInt(mingen);
        maxgen=parseInt(maxgen);

        if(mingen=="0" || maxgen=="0"){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: red;">Error. Imposible generar numero a partir de cero.</span>';
            return;
        }

        //Continuar corriendo codigo
        numero=Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxgen - mingen + 1)) + mingen;
        //alert("Número generado exitosamente utilizando "+mingen+" y "+maxgen+" como valores máximos y minimos.");

        //En caso de que no se desee utilizar un rango personalizado continuar en modo 2
    }else if(modo=="2"){
        //alert("[Cancelado] Utilizando modo estandard.")

        //Pedir valor 
        adivinar=document.getElementById("adivinar").value;

        //Cancelar codigo si el numero maximo esta vacio
        if(adivinar==""){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: #DBA901;">Por favor ingresa el numero maximo posible de genrar.</span>';
            return;
        }

        //Continuar corriendo codigo
        adivinar=parseInt(adivinar);
        if(adivinar>=100 && adivinar<=1000){
            //alert("Numero máximo seleccionado: "+adivinar);
            numero=Math.floor(Math.random()*adivinar)+1;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: #DBA901;">Por favor ingresa un numero maximo entre 100 y 1000.</span>';
            return;
        }
    }

    //Processing [PROBABLY WHERE THE ERROR IS AT]

    do{

        ingresar=document.getElementById("ingresar").value;

        //Cancelar codigo si no se pone numero
        if (ingresar==""){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: #DBA901;">Ingresa un numero a adivinar..</span>';
            return;
        }

        ingresar=parseInt(ingresar);
        contador++;

        //¿Tenes la respuesta Maikol?
        if(ingresar==numero){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: #DBA901;">El numero es: '+numero+ '¡Bien! ¡Lo Lograstes en '+contador+' veces!</span>';
            //alert("¡Bien!, ¡lo lograstes!. el número era: "+numero);
        }else{

            //Algoritmo de de aproximación a número aleatorio
            if(ingresar>numero)aproximacion=", es menor a lo que ingresastes.";else aproximacion=", es mayor a lo que ingresastes.";

            //Algoritmo de aproximacion entre dos números
            aviso=0;

            if(ingresar>numero || ingresar<numero){
                if(numero>1000 && numero>mingen && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número es mayor de ' +mingen+',además'+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<1000 && numero>700 && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número está entre 700 y 1000, además'+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<700 && numero>500 && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número está entre 500 y 700, además'+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<500 && numero>200 && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número está entre 200 y 500, además'+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<200 && numero>100 && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color:green;">El número está entre 100 y 200, además'+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<100 && numero>50  && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número está entre 50 y 100, además'+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<50 && numero<maximo && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número es menor de '+maximo+' y tambien '+aproximacion+'</span>'; aviso=1; }
                if(numero<50 && aviso==0) {document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='<span id="status" style="color: green;">El número es menor a 50'; aviso=1; }
            }
        }
    }while(ingresar!=numero);

    //Felicidades
    //alert("¡Felicidades, lograstes descubrirlo en unas "+contador+" veces!");
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>Adivina tu Número V4.1 Box</h1>Versión mejorada, acepta generar rango de valores personalizados.
    <p>¿Estás preparado para el reto?</p>
<img src="http://www.ilyke.net/uploads/2010/09/26/sub/763-7-Bursting-Light.gif" style="width:400px;eight:400px;" alt="Hola"/>
<br/><br/>

<p><h1><span id="status">You are not playing yet..</span></h1></p>
<form>
<h4>Custom Value Range</h3>
Minimum Value <input type="text" style="width:100px;" id="mingen"/><br><br>
Maximum Value <input type="text" style="width:100px;" id="maxgen"/>
</form>

<form>
<h4>Maximum number to generate in normal mode</h3>
Máximo <input type="text" style="width:100px;" id="adivinar"/><br><br>
</form>

<form>
    <h3>Adivina tu Número!</h3>
<input type"text" id="ingresar"/>
</form>

<button style="height:40px; width:150px" onclick="configuracion()">Mode Selection</button>
<button style="height:40px; width:150px" onclick="juego()">Go</button>
<p>Modo Actual: <span id="modo" style="color: red;">N/A</span></p>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you very much.**
Marcos MC

Comment: You should definitely [learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). Add a `console.log` statement in the loop to test whether it really is executed infinitely. Set breakpoints, inspect variables. Debugging 101 ;)

Comment: I can get over the infinite loop issue, the problem is that without loop i can't get the counter to work. Thanks for the guide!

Comment: Look at this way, `while(ingresar!=numero)` isn't happening. Have you tried a small range between 1-10?

Comment: You really need to simplify your code into something more easy to understand so that people can trouble shoot if for you.

Comment: There i stated that while my input number "ingresar" is not equal to the number generated i should keep repeating and adding +1 to the counter until i enter the right one, however it seems that it repeates so fast that freezes the browser and i can't even type in the text box

Comment: Your loop never changes the value of the `ingresar` input. So the `while` condition never changes.

Comment: @Jakobud I am really sorry, i tryed my best but i am still new in this, however i think that if you read it from the beggining you can have an idea how it works, maybe..

Comment: The user can't enter anything into the field while the Javascript loop is running. What you need to do is add an event handler for the user entering a number in the input, and then check whether it matches `numero`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it working, as you said @Barmar i ended up deleting the "Do" and changing the variable "contador" from local inside the function juego(), to a global one at the beggining of the script block, now it doesn't reset back to 0 each time the function in run. Thank you very much everyone.